# Chrome extension - how to pass the values to background page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a small assignment.I need help on that..i am new to this stackoverflow..
The problem is of my extension..i have tried many methods in various tutorials and articles..
i need to achieve this.
I have an extension and when i click on it ,it should capture the current url of the page and open a new tab with the url and the source code (html structure) of the page..both the sourcecode and url must be stored somewhere .. like in an object or something..

So far i have done this.

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "ncubicx",
"version": "0.0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "img/19x19.png",
      "38": "img/38x38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "That's the tool tip"
},
"permissions": [
  "activeTab",
  "tabs",
  "cookies",
  "contextMenus",
  "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
   var url = tabs[0].url;
  });
  chrome.tabs.create({url: 'newtab.html'}) ;
});
```

I dont know how to display the url in newtab.html or how to store the url's somewhere.
Hope someone helps me in this..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: So if you are at a site say www.abc.com, you want to capture this url and its html and open a new tab with same url???

Comment: @Sid not with the same url.I need to open a popup.html which display the url and the html.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the `url` of `tab` from `background` page and `html` source code from `content script`. Once you have both, open a new `tab` and send the object to this new tab where you can populate the `html` by yourself.

**Note** : Before sending the `object` to `new tab`, you need to wait for `tab` to load. So i have added a check for that.

Here's the whole code:

**manifest.json**:

```
{
  "name": "Demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "practice",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "src/bg/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
    "default_title": "browser action demo"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*","tabs"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
          "js/jquery/jquery.min.js",
        "src/content/content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**background.js:**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){

    chrome.tabs.query({active: true,currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
        var url = tabs[0].url;
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message : "getHtml"},function(response){
           var html = response.html;
            var obj ={
                tabUrl : url,
                tabHtml : html
            };
            createNewtab(obj);
        });

});
});

function createNewtab(obj){
    var targetId = null;
     chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener(tabId, changedProps) {

      if (tabId != targetId || changedProps.status != "complete")
        return;

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: "loadNewTab", data: obj});     

     });

    var newTabUrl = chrome.extension.getURL('newTab.html');
      chrome.tabs.create({ url: newTabUrl}, function(tab) {
         targetId = tab.id;         
        });
}
```

**content.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    switch (request.message){
        case "getHtml":
            var src = $("html").html();
            sendResponse({html: src});
            break;
    }
});
```

**newTab.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="src/newTab.js"></script>

    </head>
<body>

    //You can populate data as you like
    </body>

</html>
```

**newTab.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    switch (request.message){
        case "loadNewTab":
            console.log(request.data);
            //You have the object as request.data with tabUrl and tabHtml
            break;
    }
});
```